# Detect if only whitespace and formatting/div html tags exist

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I would like a way to detect if a string contains only whitespace of whitespace/formatting html tags without any content.

This is because the specific string is included on a page and should not be shown if only HTML tags ( or whitespace) are included.

Currently I have removed the whitespace using `trim`. Should I do some something like a `replaceAll` using `rexex` to remove html tags?

```
<div class="well well-large" 
ng-if="lc.displayWelcomeMessage.trim() != '' " 
ng-bind-html="lc.displayWelcomeMessage"></div>
```

Are there any ready implementations/libs/functions for this?

Comment: Try getting the text and then trim it - if it's empty, then you don't have any text ;) So .innerText.trim() should do it.

Comment: @metal03326  Oh, that's clever! I imagine you mean JQuery text method: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Yeah, just fixed it to be with pure JS ;)

Comment: @metal03326 If you want to add it as an answer I will accept! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text from the DOM element and then trim it - if the result is an empty string, then you don't have any text in that element. So `element.innerText.trim() == ''` should do the job.

Comment: Also `text().trim()` as menioned in your comment

Answer (score 2):

Write your javascript like this....

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(document.body).on('click', '.click', function(){
  var whitDiv = jQuery('.whileSpace').text();
  if(whitDiv == '')
  {
   jQuery('.whileSpace').text('empty Div');
  }
  else
    {
       jQuery('.whileSpace').text('have content');
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click">Click</div>
<div class="whileSpace"></div>
```